# Extract a specific part of a string that contains bracket and percentage symbol using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the string `"6324.13(86.36%)"`, and I'd like to extract out `86.36` only. I used the following regex, but the output still comes with the bracket and percentage character.

`re.search('\((.*?)\)',s).group(0)` -> `(86.36%)`

I used the following instead, but it returns an array containing a string without the brackets. However, I still can't remove the percentage character.

`re.findall('\((.*?)\)',s)` -> `['86.36%']`

I'm just not sure how to modify the regex to remove that `%` as well. I know I can use string slicing to remove the last character, but I just want to resolve it within the regex expression itself.

Comment: Just add the % outside of your capture group:  `re.findall('\((.*?)%\)',s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a percentage sign to the regular expression, so that it's omitted from the capture group:

```py
import re
s = "6324.13(86.36%)"
result = re.findall('\((.*?)%\)',s)
print(result) # Prints ['86.36']
```